# Update Couchdb document

Tags: couchdb, put, couchrest

I have a Couchdb document id and revision id and I would like to update the document. How can I achieve this using CouchRest?

I have tried including "_rev" in "put" as suggested somewhere but that doesn't work. This is what I've tried so far:

```
 CouchRest.put('connection/db/docid',{"_rev": "id"},"Name": "XVZ"})
```

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to read this doc : http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/tour.html#first
It might make couchdb clearer!

PS : You must specify id and rev to make it work.

Comment: I went through the documentation and looked up online also, I probably am missing something simple here. A simple example would be really helpful.